# How to make div fill td height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with 2 columns. Each `<td>` element contains a `<div>` element. How can I set height of `<div>` elements to fill owner `<td>` element?

I need to get it to work in IE too.

Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eric777/wJ4BR/) here.

Comment: Just curious, would `div{ height:100% }` work?

Comment: As far as I know, this can only be done with Javascript. @SnowBlind `height:100%` doesn't do anything unfortunately.

Comment: height:100% works in Chrome only

Comment: I'm using Chrome and `height:100%` doesn't do anything...

Comment: height:100% is interited from the parent. Each parent (body,html etc) needs to have height:100% in order for this to work.

Comment: Yes you're right. But it does not works in IE

Comment: TDs inherit their size from the size of their content, so did you change the height of the TD with a style?

Comment: No I did not. I don't want to change the height od the TD with a style

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make floating inner divs the same height as the highest div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873781/how-to-make-floating-inner-divs-the-same-height-as-the-highest-div)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$("div").each(function(){
    $(this).height( $(this).parent.height() )
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not solution for me because my table has dynamically content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't want to do this with every `td` and `div`.

```
var calculatedHeight = $('#someTD').innerHeight();

$('#innerDiv').height(calculatedHeight);
```

To be more generic, you can also use classes and a combination of SnowBlind's answer, as follows..

```
$('.someDiv').each(function(){
    var heightToSet =  $(this).parent.innerHeight();
    $(this).height(heightToSet);
});
```

**UPDATE**: You need to have a custom event when you update the cell (via ajax or however)
and repeat the above. But only for that cell.

```
$('table').delegate('td', 'onCellUpdate', function(){
     // a td triggered this, do something
});
```

and..

```
.trigger('onCellUpdate')
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? IE you mean to say? This should work for IE too.

Comment: I can edit a table cell so the table has dynamically content.

Comment: Oh, so it was not just `height`, it was `innerHeight`!! @Erik Didn't this work either?

Comment: I don't want to bind a event handler for a each cell.

Comment: You can always bind a single handler to the table using `delegate()` or `on()`

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, why not try to style the td instead of a div within a td?

That's what I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qu42z/)...