# Sidebar grows up together with the content

Tags: html, css

I created [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/A4pmb/2/). I am trying to make the content (`head` and `body` ids) and the sidebar the same height. Do you have any suggestions how can I do it? I tried `height: 100%` in the sidebar, but I guess I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581), modify your CSS like this:

Add these to `#wrap`:

```
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
```

And these to `#sidebar`:

```
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

Also here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zz2u9/).

### CSS

```
#wrap {
   margin: auto;
   width: 400px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

#sidebar {
   float: right;
   width: 100px;
   background: red;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}

#content {
   float: left;
   width: 300px;
}

#head {
   background: green;
   color: #000;
}

#body {
   background: #000;
   color: #FFF;
   min-height: 300px
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="head">Hello</div>
        <div id="body">World</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but it doesn't work well with more text: http://jsfiddle.net/zz2u9/1/

Comment: Copy that text to my version and you will see, that [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/p2v2r/). The problem in your version, is that you put the text into `<p>`s. If you want to do this add `p{margin:0;}` to your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set some height to the #wrap div eg. min-height: 500px; and than set content and sidebar to height: 100%; - that should do the trick.
-- oh, I see you have two more divs in the content div, you need to set their width as well then.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should go with js solution [equal_heights](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/)

although there is several discussion held on same problem

[HTML/CSS: Making two floating divs the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height)

[How do I keep two divs that are side by side the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height)

[How to make floating inner divs the same height as the highest div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873781/how-to-make-floating-inner-divs-the-same-height-as-the-highest-div)

Answer (score 0):

Insert the [height:] in wrap div and right div will be with full height of the body